# tf.math.top_k not accepting integers {"error": "k must be scalar, got shape [1]\n\t [[{{node TopKV2}}]]"}

Tags: python-3.x, docker, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-serving

Here is my code-

```
import tensorflow as tf    
SAVE_MODEL_PATH = "test/1"

class GetTopK(tf.Module):   
    def __init__(self):
        self.wow = "wowness!"

    @tf.function(input_signature=[
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, 5), dtype=tf.float32), 
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=None, dtype=tf.int32)])
    
    def indices(self, inp_tensor, top_k):        
        indices = tf.math.top_k(input=inp_tensor, k=top_k).indices
        return {"indices": indices}


to_export = GetTopK()
tf.saved_model.save(
    to_export, 
    SAVE_MODEL_PATH, 
    signatures={"indices": to_export.indices})
```

It is supposed to take in a tensor of shape (None, 5), and then return the indices with the highest values, using tf.math.top_k function

I am using tensorflow-gpu==2.3.0

Then I am trying to run the tf serving using docker-

```
export ModelPath="$(pwd)/test" # pwd is where the above mentioned python script exists
docker run -t --rm -p 8501:8501 -v "$ModelPath:/models/nsp" -e MODEL_NAME=nsp tensorflow/serving
    
curl -d '{"signature_name": "add", "instances":[{"x": 1.5, "y": 10}]}' -X POST http://localhost:8501/v1/models/nsp:predict
```

It throws the following error-

```
{
    "error": "k must be scalar, got shape [1]\n\t [[{{node TopKV2}}]]"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just changed

```
indices = tf.math.top_k(input=inp_tensor, k=top_k).indices
```

to

```
indices = tf.math.top_k(input=inp_tensor, k=tf.squeeze(top_k)).indices
```

and it worked. The problem was that even when I am sending an integer, tf serving converts it into a tensor, so I have to squeeze the scalar out of the tensor by using tf.squeeze